# What do ptLineDist and relativeCCW do?

Tags: java, api, geometry

I saw these methods in the [Line2D Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html)  but did not understand what they do?

Javadoc for `ptLineDist` says:

> Returns the distance from a point to this line. The distance measured is the distance between the specified point and the closest point on the infinitely-extended line defined by this `Line2D`. If the specified point intersects the line, this method returns 0.0

Doc for `relativeCCW` says:

> Returns an indicator of where the specified point (PX, PY) lies with respect to the line segment from (X1, Y1) to (X2, Y2). The return value can be either 1, -1, or 0 and indicates in which direction the specified line must pivot around its first endpoint, (X1, Y1), in order to point at the specified point (PX, PY).
>
> A return value of 1 indicates that the line segment must turn in the direction that takes the positive X axis towards the negative Y axis. In the default coordinate system used by Java 2D, this direction is counterclockwise.
>
> A return value of -1 indicates that the line segment must turn in the direction that takes the positive X axis towards the positive Y axis. In the default coordinate system, this direction is clockwise.
>
> A return value of 0 indicates that the point lies exactly on the line segment. Note that an indicator value of 0 is rare and not useful for determining colinearity because of floating point rounding issues.
>
> If the point is colinear with the line segment, but not between the endpoints, then the value will be -1 if the point lies "beyond (X1, Y1)" or 1 if the point lies "beyond (X2, Y2)".

Comment: put references where did you see that.

Comment: if you are the one who -1'd me, I already wrote JAVA DOCS. If not, I apologize :p

Comment: if my reference is correct, it is a name of class not a method

Comment: Did you click on the methods and read the (slightly more) detailed docs?

Comment: Yes, I did @AnnaLear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptLineDist` is the shortest distance between a point and a line.

One trick to note is that it's an infinitely extended line, which means that the line is extended out to infinity in either direction and *then* the distance between the line and point is determined.

I don't do 2D programming work, but this could be handy if I were trying to determine how far an object (defined by a reference point) was from the horizon line of another object.

`relativeCCW` tells you which direction a line would have to rotate in order to direct itself at a point.  (I really wanted to say "point at a point" there).

I think their definitions of clockwise / counterclockwise are backwards, but whatever, at least they're defined.  I would experiment and validate the results.

This could be useful if I had a vector or an arrow and wanted to see which direction it needed to rotate from its base in order to align with my point.  So, if I were writing a compass application, I could keep track of which way to rotate to get to North.